# No [news] is good news

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [news](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/news) metatag is old news. It only has 7 questions, including one that's spam, and is a candidate for speedy deletion.

Answer (score 4):

No news is good news

I've taken the liberty of cleaning up that tag